Difference between display of webpart in page in edit mode and page in publication
Hello i deployed my webpart on Sharepoint Online on a page and i see a difference in display between edit mode and published page. The webpart contain a scss that i use thanks to declare module "*.module.scss"; in a file typing.d.ts .
What should i do?
In the same way there is a difference between the layout in workbench and when i deploy my sspkg.
To deploy here is the process i use:

increased the build number
gulp clean then gulp build --ship, gulp bundle --ship and gulp
package-solution --ship.

Page in Edit mode

Published page


Page Edit Mode: Users who have elevated permission can add and configure Web Part on the page. Published Page: Final outcome of the page that the end users see and use it to complete the intended task that the web part is designed and configured for

And the contents of the *.scss should be included in the deployed SPFx package

@MatiurRahman yes it should be included .Do you see what im missing?

I can't tell based on the screenshots you've posted. Please list the end user expected results and what is missing in the published page. What is expected for web part to do?

I just found the solution.
Acutally in my file module.scss i changed property of labels from text-align:relative to display:  flex;
